# Recognizing ARM Software Interrupt (SWI) functions by Visual C++ compiler

Tags: c, compiler-errors, arm, visual-studio-2017, intrinsics

Because I prefer Visual Studio editor instead of Keil and IAR editors, I tried to compile ARM based projects using VS 2017. A project includes RTL.h header of RealView Run-Time Library which declares [Software Interrupt (SWI) functions](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/rlarm/rlarm_ar_swi_func.htm). As I understand [Visual C++ compiler supports SWI intrinsic function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/arm-intrinsics) but I'm getting compile errors.

Also I tried this in a main-only application compiling using default compiler and Clang compiler too - both of Visual Studio:

```
1: void __swi(1) test1();
2: void __swi_2 test2();
3: 
4: void test3() __swi(3);
5: void test4() __swi_4;
6:
7: __swi(5) test5();
8: __swi_6 void test6();
```

The errors generated by default Visual C++ compiler are:

- Line 1

  - Error    C2182   '__swi': illegal use of type 'void'
  - Error    C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'test1'
  - Error    C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
- Line 2

  - Error    C2182   '__swi_2': illegal use of type 'void'
  - Error    C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'test2'
  - Error    C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
- Line 4

  - Error    C3646   '__swi': unknown override specifier
  - Error    C2059   syntax error: '('
- Line 5

  - Error    C3646   '__swi_4': unknown override specifier
- Line 7

  - Error    C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
  - Error    C2374   '__swi': redefinition; multiple initialization
  - Error    C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'test5'
- Line 8

  - Error    C2144   syntax error: 'void' should be preceded by ';'
  - Error    C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Is Visual C++ compiler capable to recognize these declarations? If yes, what should be changed?

Comment: Maybe post some of the error messages?

Comment: Sure. I hope it will help.

Comment: "...by Visual C++ compiler" Why the C tag and not a C++ tag?

Comment: It's in fact C code. I tried to add C++ tag too but there is a limit of 5 tags only...

Comment: Changing the extension of source file from .cpp to .c there errors are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs you linked, both compilers have an `__swi` keyword or intrinsic, but it has a very different meaning in the two language extensions.  So it doesn't appear to be possible to do what you want, unless you can set up VS2017 to use ARM's compiler instead of the MS compiler that comes with that IDE.

This is the price of using language extensions that are only provided by a single compiler, especially a non-free compiler, assuming that's really the case.

---

**The details**:

According to the MS doc you linked, `__swi()` is an intrinsic for the SVC instruction, for generating software interrupts, not for writing handlers for them.

`__swi` not an attribute you can use as part of declaring another function, it's a function of its own, with prototype `unsigned int __swi(unsigned int, ...)`.  You can use it from inside another function to make a system call like this:

```
int swi1(int a) {
    return __swi(1, a);    // I didn't check any system-call lists to find out what args actually make sense
}
```

---

`void __swi(1) test1();` is the same kind of syntax error as
`void sqrt(2.0) test1();`.  Similarly `__swi_2` is just another unrecognized identifier.

Whatever you were trying to do, `__swi()` is not the right way in Visual Studio.

---

In ARM's compiler, `__swi(8)` is a function attribute meaning that callers should invoke it with `swi 8` instead of `BL function_name` (the normal call instruction).  It apparently also sets up the interrupt table to point to the functions defined with that attribute.

This is a totally different meaning and language-syntax usage from how MSVC defines it.

Comment: Well, in RealView Run-Time Library 's RTL.h is this declaration: extern void     *_alloc_box (void *box_mem) __swi (1); and the ARM compiler is able to recognize it.

Comment: @Flaviu: Does Visual Studio for ARM compile that?  It certainly looks like the two compilers have different language extensions that are not compatible, but both happen to use the same `__swi` name.

Comment: Sorry, it's about ARM compiler of ARM company.

Comment: Well, in RealView Run-Time Library 's RTL.h is this declaration: extern void *_alloc_box (void *box_mem) __swi (1); and the ARM compiler of ARM company is able to recognize it.

Comment: It looks like it's "you have to buy & use only our tool" due language extensions :)

Comment: Those language extensions are not essential.  You could write stuff in asm directly, or at least wrapper functions to dispatch to system calls.  IIRC, the GNU compiler might have an `__attribute__` to let you write an interrupt-handler, so you could still write interrupt handlers in pure C.  You'd have to set up the interrupt table yourself, though.

Comment: I just want to edit and compile using VS 2017 existing code that is successfully compiled by Keil ARM compiler.

Comment: @Flaviu: Well from the docs you linked, they both have `__swi`, but it has a very different meaning in the two language extensions.  So it doesn't appear to be possible to do what you want, unless you can set up VS2017 to use ARM's compiler instead of the MS compiler that comes with that IDE.  This is the price of using language extensions that are only provided by a single compiler, especially a non-free compiler, assuming that's really the case.

Comment: I think this is the answer.

Comment: @Flaviu: That's pretty much what the answer I posted already says: `__swi()` in MSVC doesn't work the way your source uses it.  Or did you mean using ARM's compiler as a back-end for VS's front end?

Comment: For posterity I would like a clean answer (isn't possible to create a new answer?). I expected that ARM compiler of VS is be able to compile code compiled by ARM compiler of Keil. Using ARM compiler of Keil is a possible workaround.

Comment: @Flaviu: That's fair, when I wrote the answer I'd only looked at the MS doc, so I didn't make a very definite statement about the big picture.  Updated the answer.